# TPL Exception handling

Tags: c#-4.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Per the article referenced above I am trying to handle exceptions in a continuatin task.  The example I am citing in the above article is this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new MyCustomException("Task1 faulted.");
})
.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have observed a {0}",
            t.Exception.InnerException.GetType().Name);
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

My code is:

```
Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => process.StartTask(this));
task.ContinueWith(CloseDialog, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

In StartTask, I throw an error just like the example.  My expectation is that CloseDialog will execute and I can examine task.Exception within that method as shown by the example.  However when I throw the exception I the code simply stops with an unhandled exception.  Should I be using a try/catch block? If so, where?
By the way, I want my continuation task (CloseDialog) to ALWAYS run.  I'm just using .OnlyOnFaulted because that is what is shown in the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A continuation can find out if an exception was thrown by the antecedent `Task` by the antecedent task's exception property. The following prints the results of a `NullReferenceException` to the console

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write(ant.Exception());
```

If `task1` throws an exception and this exception is not captured/queried by the continuation it is considered unhandled and the application dies. With continuations it is enough to establish the result of the task via the `Status` keyword

```
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            if (task.Exception != null)
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = task.Exception.InnerException.Message;
            else
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = "Operation failed!";
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you don't use continuations you either have to wait on the task in a `try`/`catch` block or query a task's `Result` in a `try`/`catch` block

```
int x = 0;
Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => 7 / x);
try
{
    task.Wait();
    // OR.
    int result = task.Result;
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(aggEx.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Hope this help even if it is a bit late and you know all there is by now! :]